# finding parent in tree using easyjstree

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, treeview

I've one query regarding easyjstree. I am using easytree JS file in order to work with tree view. In my scenario i want to find the parent of the child node if selected, i.e , if user selects any child node then i should know who is the parent of the node, or if user clicks on parent itself i must know that parent of this node is itself a parent and in all cases it returns me an id. 
Example :

```
 -- Root 0
     - Child 0
     - Child 1 (selected)
 -- Root 1
     - Child 0
     - Child 1
```

In above sample, if child 1 node is selected it should return me the ID of Parent Node lets say "root0".

Please see the generated HTML code :

```
<ul> 
  <li class="isFolder isExpanded" title="Bookmarks"> Folder 1 
     <ul> 
        <li><a href="google.com"; target="_blank">Go to Google.com</a></li> 
        <li><a href="yahoo.com"; target="_blank">Go to Yahoo.com</a></li>  
     </ul> 
  </li> 
  <li> Node 1 
     <ul> 
        <li>Sub Node 1</li> 
        <li>Sub Node 2</li> 
        <li>Sub Node 3</li> 
     </ul> 
  </li> 
</ul>
```

Do we have another plugin which gives these flexibility. FYI, i am using MVC4.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Amod

Comment: Do you want to get the parents value in the view (using javascript/jquery) or in the controller when you post back?

Comment: Thank you for your reply stephen- i want to get it in the view and that value will be send to contoller. Actually, when user selects the child node and click on edit button all the childs from that root needs to be open in popup.

Comment: You just need to use jquery to traverse the DOM. You would need to POST a snippet of the html generated by the plugin - its probably using `ul` and `li` elements so your would use methods such as `.closest('ul`)`

Comment: You need to edit your question - code like this in comments is unreadable

Comment: Please read my last comment. Click the edit link in your question and append the code to your original question. Do not add it in comments! (and then please delete your comments). Also, next time you add a comment, click on the adjacent help link.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Thank you for guiding me. I have modified the question and now added HTML code generated by easytree js. 

I hope this is more clear :-)

Comment: OK, So if say you select (click on?) `<li>Sub Node 1</li>` Do you want to return the value of its parent which is `<li> Node 1`. Not sure what you meant by the _ID of Parent Node_ since there does not seem to be any `ID` attribute or property - do you just want the text - i.e. "Node 1"?

Comment: @StephenMuecke - sorry for the delay reply got busy with something else :-( my bad. Id is what i am going to generate dynamically. EasyTree allows us to give own id, if not given it will generate their own. I am planning to keep id something like id="root-123", where 123 would be the ID from database. and for child it would be id="child-221", where 221 is database field id.

Comment: If say in your code `<li id="root-123">Node 1<ul><li id=child-221">Sub Node 1</li>.....`, then `$('li').click(function() { console.log($(this).parent('ul').parent('li').attr('id); });` would return "root-123" if you clicked on "Sub Node 1".  - its just a matter of navigating the DOM.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Thank you so much. I did it by using parent('ul') method only  :) thank you.